# indicator function?

Tags: analysis, notation, partial-differential-equations

Does anyone know what 
$
1_\omega v
$
means where $v \in L^2((0,T) \times \Omega )$ and $\omega \subset \subset \Omega$?

It should be an indicator function of $(t,x)$, but not sure how to interpret it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of $v$  for the characteristic function of $(0,T)\times\omega$?

Probably $1_{\omega}:(0,T)\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is the function defined by $$1_{\omega}(t,x)=\{1,\textrm{ for }x\in\omega, 0,\textrm{ for }x\in\Omega\setminus\omega\}.$$